# Pc powered off while resizing moving partition

Tags: gparted, grubrescue

While GParted was at the last step of resizing the Linux partition (moving it to the left or something) I pressed my power off button by mistake. I booted up in GParted again and did a disk check/fix on my sda2. Now I can't boot back in Linux. Is there a way to fix the boot using the terminal available in the GParted live USB?

Comment: IF a partition was being moved, it is without any doubt corrupt now. Preferably, you you will fully erase the disk, repartition and reinstall from scratch, although deleting the affected partition and recreating it may or may not work.